# How to make divs,added by jquery in woocommerce checkout form, dynamic, or exactly inside the form?

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce

I needed to add some static divs inside the checkout form, not before or after form, like I found adding by hooks, so I simply used jQuery.

```
jQuery('p#billing_first_name_field').before('<div class="form-row form-row-first personal_details_toggle"><div class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><div class="input-text form-control" id="personal_details_toggle">Personal details of recepient<span class="fa-arrow-down"></span></div></div></div>');
jQuery('p#billing_country_field').before('<div class="form-row form-row-first delivery_address"><div class="woocommerce-input-wrapper"><div class="input-text form-control" id="delivery_address">Delivery address<span class="fa-arrow-down"></span></div></div></div>');
```

But now their text 'Delivery address' and 'Personal details of recepient' have to be translated.
I can't paste (I use customizer) instead of text inside jQuery, it's empty if I try.
They have to be exactly in that places and translated somehow, what's the right way to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Since Wordpress 5.0 you can make your JavaScript strings translatable just like you do with PHP.  See this article for details on how to do it: [New! JavaScript i18n support in WordPress 5.0](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2018/11/09/new-javascript-i18n-support-in-wordpress/)

If the translations are only available at runtime from PHP you can use [wp_localize_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_localize_script/) when you enqueue the script.  For example,

```
// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );
 
// Localize the script with new data
$translation_array = array(
    'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate', 'plugin-domain' ),
    'a_value' => '10'
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );
 
// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

Then you can access the variables in JavaScript like this:

```
alert( object_name.some_string );
```

Comment: if it's not official string translation with _e or __, it's mine customizer option, 'echo get_theme_mod', what should I write?

Comment: So are you saying that this value can only be accessed at runtime by calling get_theme_mod() in PHP?

Comment: Yes, I usually do it in customizer (or acf,) There are not many of them. I didn't install acf, use customizer.

Comment: I'm trying to do like that, the string is not translated, where am I wrong? My added stings are in main.js, should I place them separately?  
wp_register_script( 'some_handle',  get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js' ); 
// Localize the script with new data
$translation_array = array(
    'Delivery address' => get_theme_mod('delivery_address_text'),    
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'main_js', $translation_array );
 
// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );

Comment: You should edit your question to show more details of what you're doing exactly and what doesn't work.  Show the PHP where you enqueue the script and show the updated JavaScript that is not working.